# Concatenate outputs of LSTM in Keras

Tags: keras, nlp, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I intend to feed all outputs of timesteps from a LSTM to a fully-connected layer. However, the following codes fail. How can I reduce 3D output of LSTM to 2D by concatenating each output of timestep?

```
X = LSTM(units=128,return_sequences=True)(input_sequence)
X = Dropout(rate=0.5)(X)
X = LSTM(units=128,return_sequences=True)(X)
X = Dropout(rate=0.5)(X)
X = Concatenate()(X)
X = Dense(n_class)(X)
X = Activation('softmax')(X)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Flatten`](https://keras.io/layers/core/#flatten) layer to flatten the 3D output of LSTM layer to a 2D shape.

As a side note, it is better to use `dropout` and `recurrent_dropout` arguments of [LSTM layer](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#lstm) instead of using `Dropout` layer directly with recurrent layers.

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain a little about why it is better to use them as arguments of LSTM layer?

Comment: @XINLIU Essentially, the proper way of applying dropout in recurrent layers is to use the **same** dropout mask at every timestep. It should not vary temporally since it hinders the learning process. I think Yarin Gal showed this for the first time in his [PhD thesis](http://mlg.eng.cam.ac.uk/yarin/blog_2248.html).  You can set both arguments (note that they are different things) and compare the result with the result you got in case of using Dropout layers.

Comment: Thanks! In Keras there is a CuDNNLSTM layer. However, there is no "dropout" or "recurrent_dropout" argument in CuDNNLSTM layer.

Answer (score 0):

Additional to @todays answer:
It seems like you want to use return_sequences just to concatenate it into a dense layer. If you did not already try it with return_sequeunces=False, I would recommend you to do to so. The main purpose of return_sequences is to stack LSTMS or to make seq2seq predictions. In your case it should be enough to just use the LSTM.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have tried return_sequences=False, so I may want to see what the effect of this approach.